# Hash with 3 different keys each pointing to an array of instances. How do I sort the arrays by id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a hash like so:

```
def my_requests
    result = {
      accepted: [],
      rejected: [],
      pending: [],
    }
self.requests.each do |request|
  serialized_request = RequestSerializer.new(request)
  if request.accept == nil
    result[:pending].push(serialized_request)
  elsif request.accept
    result[:accepted].push(serialized_request)
  else
    result[:rejected].push(serialized_request)
  end
end

    result
  end
```

I will have a logged in user. I am trying to organize the logged in user's availabilities by id.

How do I sort each array by id. I know if this was just an array I can do:

```
array.sort_by{|request| request.id}
```

But how do I iterate through each key's array? I've tried multiple different ways and the only one that works is if I end up mapping over the hash and then another loop to sort the requests. But that doesn't return a hash. Is there a way for me to keep the structure and sort it?

The availabilities serializer is below:

```
class RequestSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :start_time, :payment, :number_of_hours, :availability_id, :date, :name, :accept, :postcode, :phone_number
end
```

Below is one of the key, value pair outputs.

```
:rejected=>[#<RequestSerializer:0x00007fa416e168a8 @object=#<Request id: 64, payment: 200, number_of_hours: 20, accept: false, start_time: "2000-01-01 16:20:00", venue_id: 1, availability_id: 4, created_at: "2020-08-30 12:15:04", updated_at: "2020-08-30 12:15:52">, @instance_options={}, @root=nil, @scope=nil>, #<RequestSerializer:0x00007fa416e167b8 @object=#<Request id: 4, payment: 160, number_of_hours: 4, accept: false, start_time: "2000-01-01 16:15:00", venue_id: 2, availability_id: 5, created_at: "2020-06-17 21:19:07", updated_at: "2020-06-17 21:21:32">, @instance_options={}, @root=nil, @scope=nil>, #<RequestSerializer:0x00007fa416e166c8 @object=#<Request id: 71, payment: 100, number_of_hours: 1, accept: false, start_time: "2000-01-01 09:45:00", venue_id: 1, availability_id: 6, created_at: "2020-10-01 08:45:43", updated_at: "2020-10-01 08:46:04">, @instance_options={}, @root=nil, @scope=nil>, #<RequestSerializer:0x00007fa416e16560 @object=#<Request id: 66, payment: 30, number_of_hours: 3, accept: false, start_time: "2000-01-01 16:30:00", venue_id: 1, availability_id: 26, created_at: "2020-08-30 12:31:02", updated_at: "2020-08-30 12:32:10">, @instance_options={}, @root=nil, @scope=nil>, #<RequestSerializer:0x00007fa416e163f8 @object=#<Request id: 68, payment: 20, number_of_hours: 3, accept: false, start_time: "2000-01-01 12:00:00", venue_id: 1, availability_id: 28, created_at: "2020-09-01 08:17:26", updated_at: "2020-09-01 13:09:54">, @instance_options={}, @root=nil, @scope=nil>]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Never mind I didn't get it to work. It re-ordered the first couple instances then stopped.

Comment: This is is tagged [tag:ruby-on-rails] so I assume that you are running some database query to retrieve `requests`? If so, it might make more sense to let the database do the sorting.

Comment: Hi Stefan, so I have the requests controller index. That has:
@requests = current_user.my_requests
Then that is passed to json. 
How would I go about ordering it? I mean I know I can do .order(id: :desc) but that didn't work

Comment: What does `self.requests` do?

Comment: So this method is in the user model. So self.requests is just user.requests as they have a belongs_to / has_many relationshop I believe?

Comment: In that case, `requests.order(:id).each do |...|` should work.

Comment: oh amazing. I tried to use something similar but Im not overly familiar with that way. Thanks so much. Will defo have a go and get back to you if i can't figure it out haha.

Comment: Thanks again for the extra input!

Comment: Out of curiousity Stefan? Is that current_user.my_requests.order(:id)...??

Comment: No, you have to call `order` on the relation, i.e. replace `self.requests.each do |request|` in your method with `requests.order(:id).each do |request|` (that `self.` isn't needed)

Comment: Now that I look at that, it makes so much sense. So is that querying and ordering it all before I split them into their necessary arrays.

Comment: `order` affects the database query (take a look at your rails server log) so the results you get back are already ordered. And sequentially putting ordered items into different arrays will preserve their relative order.

Comment: yep yep. Got it. Amazing thank you for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
result.transform_values { |array| array.sort_by(&:request_id) }
```

If the arrays are not not arrays of requests, but `RequestSerializer`, just call `.object` on them to get the request to sort by.

```
result.transform_values do |array|
  array.sort_by { |serializer| serializer.object.request_id }
end
```

Another option would be to define `request_id` on `RequestSerializer`

Answer (score 0):

You have to sort each hash value separately:

```
result.each_value { |array| array.sort_by!(&:id) }
```

[`Hash#each_value`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Hash.html#each_value-method) traverses the values and [`sort_by!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/Array.html#sort_by-21-method) sorts the array in-place.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a new sorted copy:

```rb
result.each_with_object({}) do |(key, value), list|
  list[key] = value.sort_by(&:id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As Stefan posted in the comments. I can use a database query to order the requests prior to splitting them into their arrays.

The answer that worked (without doing multiple loops) was:

```
def my_requests
    result = {
      accepted: [],
      rejected: [],
      pending: [],
    }

    requests.order(:id).each do |request| 
      serialized_request = RequestSerializer.new(request)
      if request.accept == nil
        result[:pending].push(serialized_request)
      elsif request.accept
        result[:accepted].push(serialized_request)
      else
        result[:rejected].push(serialized_request)
      end
    end
    result
 
     end
```

Simply by removing self. and using the .order query and the id attribute, everything comes out ordered!

Thanks Stefan! (and everyone else)

(Others worked with multiple methods or loops but as I was using Rails, the query is the quickest and easiest).